# VS2008 Tests stuck in pending

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest

I have VS2008 SP1 on windows 7.
Suddenly, the tests fail to start.

When I choose to run test(s) it gets stuck on 'Pending' forever without displaying an error.
I saw the solutions on the net talking about capital letters in the computer name. Well, my computer was already in capital so I tried to change it to lower but nothing changed. Afterwards, I changed it back to upper case - still nothing.

I also uninstalled and re-installed VS2008, but end up in the same situation.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this happen when you try running one simple, single test, like `Assert.IsTrue(true)`? I have seen this behavior with code that's caught in a deadlock situation, for example.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your addons? i have had a similar problem, after doing some analysis i have found the problem to be with one of my addons (one of them was behaving in an unpredictable manner and was causing an error whenever i tried to run a test), fixing the addon fixed my problem.

in order to find the problem:

1. enable logging on the vsTest ([how to enable logging for VSTS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yutong/archive/2006/10/03/how-to-enable-vsts-logging_3f00_.aspx))
2. run your tests and check the created log file for errors.

This should point you in the right direction